# how do i solve the following error when I am adding a toast notification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
src/components/Home/Home.js
  Line 150:37:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 150:48:  'id' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 152:28:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
```

Facing the following errors, anyone know how to solve?

```
import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
toast.configure();
function Home(props) {
  //undo toast notification
  const Undo = ({ onUndo, closeToast }) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
      onUndo();
      closeToast();
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          Row Deleted <button onClick={handleClick}>UNDO</button>
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  };

const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
      Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
        (response) => {
          toast(<Undo onUndo={() => dispatch({ id, type: "UNDO" })} />, {
            // hook will be called whent the component unmount
            onClose: () => dispatch({ type: "CLEAN_COLLECTION" }),
          });
          setCustomerList(
            customerList.filter((val) => {
              return val.ID !== ID;
            })
          );
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

hi i am trying to add a toast notification with undo button from react toastify but these errors are faced how do i solve it? <-- I do not wish to use redux can I achieve the same functionality?

Comment: You're using `dispatch`, but you don't want to use Redux. So where's your `dispatch` coming from? It might help to look at the [documentation for context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and [`useReducer`](https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/).

Comment: @Andy can i not use redux to implement undo button on toast notification?

Comment: You said in your question you _didn't_ want to use Redux.

Comment: @Andy Yes i do not want to use redux, can I still implement an undo button on react toast notifcation, right now the notification shows up butno undo button only a close button